# tkinter PhotoImage doesn't exist?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file='blueface.png')
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The image face.png is in the same directory as this .py script, but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
 line 5, in <module>
    photo = PhotoImage(file='blueface.png')
 line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
 line 3495, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "face.png": no such file or directory
```

Comment: Your sample code has a filename of `blueface.png`, but your text description mentions `face.png`.  Which is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter very much that the image is in the same folder as the script, when you call the file like that without a path python assumes it's in the same folder that you were working on when you started the script. For example, if both the script and the image are in `temp` folder, and you started your script like this:

```
python temp/script.py
```

The interpreter doesn't realize that `blueface.png` is also in `temp` and looks for it in the folder that you were in, in this case the parent of `temp`

What you should do, is either use absolute paths, or use the `__file__` to get the full script address first. For example:

```
photo = PhotoImage(file='/absolute/path/to/image/blueface.png')
```

Or using the current script's location to build the image's path:

```
import os
base_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
image_path = os.path.join(base_folder, 'blueface.png')
photo = PhotoImage(file=image_path)
```

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` won't help if this is an imported module. Much better and neater to use `__file__`.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of tkinter can not handle .png's that well. Try making the file a .gif. Or use the PhotoImage from PIL:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('blueface.png'))
label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```