# no such file or directory python image

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to put an image on a tkinter button but it doesn't see to work.

```
root.geometry('512x512')
vbuckimage = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='vbuckicon.gif')
#vbucks button
vbucksButton = tkinter.Button(root,image=vbuckimage,height=5,width=10)

vbucksButton.place(x=256,y=256)
root.mainloop()
```

the image is in the same place as the .py file

Comment: It's looking for the file relative to your current working directory, which may not be the same as the location of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124866/tkinter-photoimage-doesnt-exist)
Try this solution :

```
import os
from tkinter import *
base_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
image_path = os.path.join(base_folder, 'vbuckicon.gif')
vbuckimage = PhotoImage(file=image_path)
```